# Powershell - Get-DistributionGroup exporting to csv issue

Tags: powershell

The below command will output the correct information to the screen, however when exporting to a csv file it looks nothing like what is shown on the screen. I have been able to export with other cmdlets, Get-DistributionGroup seems to corrupt the data when using with export.csv.

```
 Outputting to screen works great!
 Get-DistributionGroup  | Where {$_.emailaddresses -like "*@adomain.com*"} | FT  Name,Alias,EmailAddresses

 Exporting to csv doesnt work correctly
 Get-DistributionGroup  | Where {$_.emailaddresses -like "*@adomain.com*"} | FT  Name,Alias,EmailAddresses | Export-csv C:/thisis.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Format-Table` (alias: `ft`) you should use `Select-Object`. `Export-Csv` expects objects as input, not formating instructions.

`Format-Table`, by definition, will convert objects to something that looks well in your output, but it's one way trip: you loose original objects as a part of the process.

`Select-Object` on the other hand can create objects with subset of properties, so that cmdlets like `Export-Csv` can still use data from original source.

**EDIT**

Thing I missed originally: you try to export a property that is a collection (EmailAddresses). That won't work unless you 'flatten' the collection first:

```
Get-DistributionGroup  | Where {$_.emailaddresses -like "*@adomain.com*"} | select Name,Alias, @{
    Name = 'EmailAddresses'
    Expression = { $_.EmailAddresses -join '|' }
}
```

Comment: I tried Select-Object and the csv output is blank. ie. Get-DistributionGroup  | Where {$_.emailaddresses -like "*@adomain.com*"} | Select-Object  Name,Alias,EmailAddresses | Export-csv C:/thisis.csv

Comment: I see typo in filter (missing '*'). That could give you blank results, yes... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you the answer has been resolved.

BartekB's answer

Get-DistributionGroup  | Where {$*.emailaddresses -like "*@adomain.com*"} | select Name,Alias, @{
    Name = 'EmailAddresses'
    Expression = { $*.EmailAddresses -join '|' }
}